# Python custom module import issue

Tags: python, import

```
test/
    scripts/
            __init__.py
            a.py
            main.py
```

The structure above is what I tested this with.

```
#Gives 0 warnings or errors before running code
from scripts import a #ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'

#Gives 1 warning (import not resolved)
import a #runs fine
```

why does that happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "scripts" module, as you've declared it, will only be found if your PYTHONPATH has .../test as one of the possibilities. If you're running inside a venv, you can create a .pth file containing the path you want and then stick it in venv/lib/[python-version]/site-packages . If you're not, just edit the PYTHONPATH environment variable (don't know what OS; how to do it depends on that info). Using just "import a" will work fine if you're running the script (I assume main) from the scripts directory, as cwd is typically part of the path already.